# Python, Numpy - Normalize a matrix/array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, normalization

This is most likely a dumb question but being a beginner in Python/Numpy I will ask it anyways. I have come across a lot of posts on how to **Normalize an array/matrix** in numpy. But I am not sure about the WHY. Why/When does an array/matrix need to be normalized in numpy? When is it used?

Normalize can have multiple meanings in difference context. My question belongs to the field of Data Analytics/Data Science. What does Normalization mean in this context? Or more specifically in what situation should I normalize an array?

The second part to this question is - What are the different methods of Normalization and can they be used interchangeably in all situations?

The third and final part - can Normalization be used for Arrays of any dimensions?

Links to any reference material (for beginners) will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider trying to cluster objects with two numerical attributes A and B. Both are equally important. Attribute A can range from 0 to 1000 and attribute B can range from 0 to 5.

If you did not normalize A and B you would end up with attribute A completely overpowering attribute B when applying any standard distance metric.

Comment: Thanks it does make sense. I am from a web development background and I guess this question needs to be answered by Statistics more than programming.